# `use_import_from' is not an exported object from 'namespace:usethis`

Tags: r, r-usethis

While developping an R package, I'm trying to use the function `usethis::use_import_from()` to import in the package a single function from another package but the function is not available whatever way I'm trying : loading `usethis` or `devtools` or explicitly writing the name with `::`. It is not available in the help either. However, it is well documented [here](https://usethis.r-lib.org/reference/use_import_from.html) and I can see it in the source code [here](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/blob/master/R/use_import_from.R):

```
> usethis::use_import_from("stats", "runif")
Error: 'use_import_from' is not an exported object from 'namespace:usethis'
```

I am using RStudio 1.3.1056, R 4.0.4, usethis 2.0.1 on Windows 10 and RStudioServer 1.1.1717, R 4.1.0, usethis 2.0.1 on Linux and have the same problem on both.

I know that I could insert the line in the description myself but there seems to be a series of checks on this function that makes it more secure.

Anybody can help ?

Comment: That function is not in the released version 2.0.1 of `usethis`, it's in the development version on Github.  Not sure why the pkgdown page doesn't make that clear, but the version number there is 2.0.1.9000, which indicates a devel version in the scheme they use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, I think @user2554330 answered my question. Your answer makes sense but I wonder how I could find out since the function is in the master of the github repo and in the documentation. If you confirm that it is just about the versioning, I will close the question.

Comment: Generally speaking master (or for some, main) branches of Github repositories are unreleased development versions.  And usually the help page will indicate that:  seems to be a bug in their web page generation, so that's their fault, not yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `usethis::use_import_from()` function is not in the released version 2.0.1 of usethis, it's in the development version on Github.   Usually the online help page would indicate that, but in this case they've forgotten to flag it, so the page shows version 2.0.1.9000 (where the 9000 signals a development version in the scheme they use), but calls it a "Released version".

If you want to use it anyway, you can install directly from Github instead of from CRAN using

```
remotes::install_github("r-lib/usethis")
```

Do be aware that since it's a development version, it hasn't been tested as carefully as the released version on CRAN.  The bug in the web page won't cause much trouble now you know about it, but there may be others that are more serious.